# Dealing with inherently long running tests (http requests)

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have a couple of tests that make an http request.  By their nature, these tests tend to take at least 500ms.  I'll probably end up having to add more, and I think that eventually all of the requests will make the test suite take prohibitively long to run.  There's also the issue of requiring an internet connection that's fast enough to run them.

There are several possible ways to get around these:

- Update my `npm test` script to purposely exclude these tests.

  - I could also add another script that includes the tests, like `test-all`.  Not sure if there is any convention on that or if `test` should do all the tests and `fast-test` or something should skip them.
- Add `.skip` to these slow tests

  - This requires changing the test files when you actually want to test, so I'd prefer not to do this.
- Some command-line argument in mocha that can explicitly skip tests.  I'm not sure there is such a thing, though.

Is there any preferred way for dealing with tests that inherently take a long time to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid writing tests which take a long time to run, unless they're integration tests.

Preferrably, unit tests should be mocking the responses, or asserting the requests were made with such-and-such parameters, rather than actually performing an HTTP request and asserting on the response.

Comment: The parsing of the actual response is the important part.  I could easily write a mock object that returned the headers and body that I know ahead of time will pass the test, but that seems to defeat the purpose of the test.  If I were to do that, how would I approach that in node since the module making the requests uses `require("request")`.  Is there a standard method for changing node modules to inject dependencies for this purpose?

Comment: You can use [proxyquire](https://npmjs.org/package/proxyquire) to fake out `require`d dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

These situations are called 'boundary tests'. The way people generally deal with 'boundary tests' where they access files, make database queries or do other non-code things is like this:

First, don't make the http requests directly in your classes code, instead make another class in charge of http requests.

Then, have your original class call on the other class to make all of the http requests you need.

Lastly, in your tests, sub out the http class so that no actual http requests are being made and, and the original class can still be tested thoroughly.

Now you only need to test the new http class making an actual http request once. All other tests will be using the mocked http class.